# PHP - Display an error when the time that you enter is not available or hits the unavailable time of a user

Tags: php, time, appointment, timetable

Pls Help me! im NOOB still studying, I want to make a module that when you enter the unavailable time or the time that you enter hits the unavailable time, it will shows an error an if you enter available time of a user it will send to the database

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn about how to [ask] a good question.  We generally help with code that has already been written

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, in html if you are using tag "input",  exists type like datetime-local, that don't allow the user write a unavailable datetime. In the database is the same thing, you can use in your table/columns the type datetime. 
But be carefull, you have to send the database a datetime, that allows the database store the information. Like this if you database only allows like this "2012-11-23 17:06:06" is has to be like this, if not it will be not store